# Trigger webservice

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webservice that I can trigger to do various stuff by typing in the URL in a browser with some defined parameters: 
Example:

```
http://hsserver/HomeSeer_REST_API.aspx?function=setdevicebyname&param1=bedroomlight&param2=on
```

I am building a web front end in plain HTML but cannot find a way to do this trigger without opening a new page in the broswer.
It would be preferable if it was a function like:

UPDATE: Got it to work with this code, but cant get the parameters to work (func,param1,param2) when I call it with

```
<button type="button" onclick="processnew('setdevicebyname','bedroom desktop light','off')">processnew</button>

   function processnew(func,param1,param2)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","HomeSeer_REST_API.aspx?function=setdevicebyname&param1=bedroom%20desktop%20light&param2=off",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

I have no clue where to look for this - hoping for some help

Comment: Look into AJAX requests.

Comment: You can look into the native JavaScript XML http request here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

XHR baby.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

or jquery's abstraction [ajax generic, or post/get for shortcuts]

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I got it to work with an example from W3schools - the ink you posted. Thanks!

Comment: Great!  My desire was to write you an example for both of these but the two doc pages do such a great job of giving you the details and examples that it seemed silly.  +1 to Kamil's node toward jQuery saving you from browser headaches.  You almost always end up abstracting native XHR and jQuery does a great job for you.

Answer (score 0):

well... that would be a simple HTTP GET request.

if you use jQuery, check this out: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/
if you want to stick to plain javascript (I wouldn't recommend that though due to some incompatibilities across browsers): http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://hsserver/HomeSeer_REST_API.aspx?function=setdevicebyname&param1=bedroomlight&param2=on',
    method: 'GET' // HTTP request method
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log('Response from server: ' + data);
});
```